# How to select database that begin with start value?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, offset

I want to select value from database that start with a dynamic input like this

```
SELECT * FROM employee  OFFSET JoinDate = '$input' LIMIT 7
```

I'd like to select all the field in employee table where JoinDate start from the input, let say from '25-03-2014' until 7 days later.
But the offset is wrong. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you paste a sample of your table? The SQL statements in the answers below are correct, so your issue lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT *
  FROM employee
 WHERE JoinDate >= '$input'
   AND JoinDate <= '$input' + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

or use `BETWEEN`

Comment: I've tried, query is okay but has no result. I also tried JoinData <= '$input' AND JoinData >= '$input' - INTERVAL 7 DAY but still has no result. Where was my mistake?

Comment: what's the `JoinData` field type?

Comment: @Dagon I set JoinData which is containing join date to text. Is that the problem?

Comment: yes, it should be a date type field or the "+ INTERVAL 7 DAY" (and any other date specific functions) wont work

Answer (score 1):

Is the table ordered by date? If you want to select the 7 records right after the search hit - I think you could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE JoinDate >= '$input' LIMIT 7 ORDER BY JoinDate ASC;
```

If you want to select all dates within a range, you could:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE JoinDate >= '$input' AND JoinDate <= '$input' + INTERVAL 7 DAY ORDER BY JoinDate ASC;
```

Comment: If using Limit, it couldn't go through another month. search result stay at the month of input. When I tried using interval, it has no result, but no error at query

Comment: `LIMIT` only limits the number of rows that you get. I think the query is correct, @Dagon 's is the same , so the problem is not the statement.

Comment: yep.. I'll fix the data type

Answer (score -1):

Use Interval:

> SELECT * FROM employee WHERE JoinDate >= '$input' AND JoinDate <=
>   '$input' + INTERVAL 7 DAY

Comment: JoinData is different from JoinDate